# Webpack server non documented property exists?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-dev-middleware

Documentation is mentioning that

> Options that are compatible with webpack-dev-middleware have  next
>   to them.

I can't find anything about "cookieDomainRewrite" but if I use it works

Any explanations? Or ideas how I can investigate it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a `http-proxy-middleware` option, the webpack-dev-server proxy appears to be using it. They mention this in the webpack [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) down at the `devServer.proxy`
section.

> The dev-server makes use of the powerful http-proxy-middleware package. Check out its documentation for more advanced usages.

I'm guessing you've found one of it `devServer.proxy`'s advanced uses. As stated you can read more over at the `http-proxy-middleware` [documentation](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options)